# Calling pytorch 0.4 from Matlab

Tags: python, linux, matlab, pytorch

I'm trying to run a python a code that uses **Pytorch 0.4** from Matlab, by using a system call (Matlab's `"system"` or `"unix"` commands), and I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/gil/PycharmProjects/test123/AugmentedTrain.py", line 3, in
>   
>       import torch   File "/home/gil/anaconda2/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/**init**.py",
>   line 78, in 
>       from torch._C import * RuntimeError: stoi

According to what I see over the internet, it is a problem of pytorch 0.4 and indeed it does not occur in pytorch 0.3. Unfortunately, porting my code to 0.3 is a lot of work and does not feel like the right thing to do (going backward).

Can anyone help?

Comment: No solution but I'm also having this issue...